# Unable to use database properties file in JavaLite

Tags: java, spark-java, activejdbc, javalite

Could not load database properties file.

I have my `database.properties` file in class path resources folder and I have configured `activejdbc.properties` at root of `classpathenv.connections.file=MyProject/src/main/resources/database.properties`

I am using mvn to run my app:

```
mvn process-classes

mvn activejdbc-instrumentation:instrument

mvn package

mvn compile exec:java
```

When I run the app with `Base.open()`, I get error:

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Could not find configuration in a property file for environment: development. Are you sure you have a database.properties file configured?
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.open(DB.java:151)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.Base.open(Base.java:52)
        at com.soul.seeker.Application.lambda$main$0(Application.java:52)
        at spark.FilterImpl$1.handle(FilterImpl.java:62)
        at spark.http.matching.BeforeFilters.execute(BeforeFilters.java:48)
        at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:129)
        at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
```

**update:**

Running the sample from javalite github is working fine, however, changing this with [spark routing](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#routes), its throwing error:

```
get("/role_on_login", (req, res) -> {
    Base.open();

    Person director = new Person("Stephen Spielberg");
    director.saveIt();

    director.add(new Movie("Saving private Ryan", 1998));
    director.add(new Movie("Jaws", 1982));
    List data = director.getAll(Movie.class);
    Base.close();

    return data;
});
```

**Error:**

```
[qtp1213754379-16] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - //localhost:4567/role_on_login
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: there is no connection 'default' on this thread, are you sure you opened it?
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.connection(DB.java:754)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.createStreamingPreparedStatement(DB.java:521)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.find(DB.java:512)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList.hydrate(LazyList.java:329)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.AbstractLazyList.toString(AbstractLazyList.java:190)
        at spark.serialization.DefaultSerializer.process(DefaultSerializer.java:38)
        at spark.serialization.Serializer.processElement(Serializer.java:49)
        at spark.serialization.Serializer.processElement(Serializer.java:52)
        at spark.serialization.Serializer.processElement(Serializer.java:52)
        at spark.serialization.SerializerChain.process(SerializerChain.java:53)
        at spark.http.matching.Body.serializeTo(Body.java:72)
        at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:189)
        at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So seems like a thread issue where javalite `Base.open()` creates a thread named "default" and spark is not able comprehend the thread with name "default"

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how Maven life cycles work.

1. No need to call `mvn activejdbc-instrumentation:instrument`
2. Do not execute `compile` before `exec.java`

Just do this:

```
mvn package
mvn exec:java
```

Since  you did not provide any additional info on your pom.xml, I assume it is typical for ActiveJDBC Maven configuration.

Comment: Best place for you to start is this sample project: https://github.com/javalite/simple-example

Comment: Using `mvn package mvn exec:java` and running the app still gives the same error: `org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Could not find configuration in a property file for environment: development. Are you sure you have a database.properties file configured?`

Comment: Tried with: `github.com/javalite/simple-example` which gives the same error: `Caused by: org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Could not find configuration in a property file for environment: development. Are you sure you have a database.properties file configured?`

Comment: A sample working project would help everyone. Check out github.com/javalite/simple-example and see it has same issues.

Comment: this sample project works as expected: https://github.com/javalite/simple-example. Please, follow directions on the README page.

Comment: Running `java -classpath target/dependency:target/classes activejdbc.examples.simple.Main` throws `Error: Could not find or load main class activejdbc.examples.simple.Main` So it is NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED

Comment: @kittu, I just tested, it is absolutely working as expected. Please, follow the README file instruction.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I have tried so many times with line by line instructions in `readme` file but I am getting error: `could not find main class`. I don't know why it is not working for me. I am using command line to run commands :(

Comment: I try to record my screen while running commands and send you the link so you can see

Comment: @kittu, here is the output from running this example step by step: https://gist.github.com/ipolevoy/5fcd18d2a1b3ca85573fe194c6cad285. It just works, please see if you miss a step.

Comment: It is working on your system, but it is not working for others. I have tried it in a new system I purchased the other day. Same error that `main method is not found`. May be some thing is missing in the documentation. Here is the youtube link I have recorded with all the steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmDkbadeDWw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @kittu, the errors `Error: Could not find or load main class activejdbc.examples.simple.Main` and `Caused by: org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Could not find configuration in a property file for environment` are different. Surely there is something is wrong in the way you execute. Unfortunately the video is not working. Can you please fix the video?

Comment: Have you seen the video? Waiting for your reply?

Comment: So what do you think? I have executed all the steps properly in the video. What could be the issue?

Comment: @kittu, the problem you are having is because you are using Linux path format on Windows. The instructions are for classpath using a Linux format: `target/dependency:target/classes`. Please, note a colon `:`. On Windows your path separator is a semi-colon: `java -classpath target/dependency;target/classes activejdbc.examples.simple.Main`.

Comment: You are right. Finally it worked but the main problem is `Base.open()` which creates a thread named `Default` and javaspark is not able to understand it if I am not wrong. Updated the question. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a second answer to the second part of your question you added last.

The reason you do not have a connection is because ActiveJDBC is lazy by default: http://javalite.io/lazy_and_eager. This means that at the time you execute your Spark `get()` method, you open and ***close*** the connection to the database. The `data` object you pass to a view did not have a chance to load data from the database. There are three ways to solve this:

1. Cause direct trip to the database:

   Base.open();

   ```
   Person director = new Person("Stephen Spielberg");
   director.saveIt();

   director.add(new Movie("Saving private Ryan", 1998));
   director.add(new Movie("Jaws", 1982));
   List data = director.getAll(Movie.class);
   data.size(); // <<<-- force trip to database before closing connection
   Base.close();
   return data;
   ```
2. Use Spark filters top open and close DB connections and do not pollute code in your `get()` methods: http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#filters
3. Use ActiveWeb which is nicely integrated with ActiveJDBC: http://javalite.io/activeweb

Comment: ok I went through the docs `In order to pre-populate the list before passing it off, you need to call any method that will force loading (hydrating) of the list from the database i.e. list.size()` and I have used spark `before()` and `after()` filter but it still throws the same error: `Could not find configuration in a property file for environment: development. Are you sure you have a database.properties file configured?`

Comment: @kittu, if this is happening, you need to look into why the file is not there. See how you package and deploy your WAR file. The file `database.properties` should be on the classpath of your project when running on the web container. This must be simple!